# Timeout Method in Java

Tags: java

So my question is really not important, but I'm writing a program that solves all sorts of algebraic equations.  I'm using Java, which I'm fairly new to, and I wondered if there was any method like SetTimeout() in JavaScript.  This is the language I've been using for quite a while, and I've used it a lot.

My actual program consists of lots of code and like 10 different files, so I can't post all of it here to show you exactly what I'm doing, but is there a simple way to set a timeout?  Basically, at the end of my program, I want to print "Program has Ended" and then wait 5 seconds and go System.exit(0).

I know how to print the words on the screen and end the program, just not how to wait five seconds in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Thread.sleep(long millis)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29), which

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds.

For example:

```
System.out.println("Program has Ended");
try {
   Thread.sleep(5000); //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to get done is make the `main thread` sleep for a specific period of time which you can accomplish through `Thread.sleep(time_in_milliseconds)`. For your case it is 5 seconds or 5000 milliseconds